# C program to find the number of onto functions and to display all the functions

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, discrete-mathematics

I have to write a C program (for my Discrete Mathematics assignment) that finds the number of onto functions from set `A (|A| = m)` to set `B (|B|=n)` and to display all those functions. Number of onto functions I calculated using the code:

```
for(k=0; k<n; k++)
    x = x + pow( -1, k) * combination( n, n - k ) * pow( ( n - k ), m);
```

Where combination is a function that finds the Number of possible combinations.

For example if A = {1,2,3}, B={a,b,c} then the number of onto functions evaluated from the formula is
3^3 - 3(2^3) + 3 = 6.
One possible solution is f = {(1,a),(2,b),(3,c)} [I know this is a solution].

But my problem is: How to display each and every solution!?
This is just a trivial example. But if m and n values are increased (provided m>=n) then the number of possible onto functions increases exponentially!!
For example if m=7 and n=4 there are 8400 functions!

I can't think of any method to display each and every function that exists between A and B.

Comment: It isn't very clear what it is that you are asking. Perhaps take a very small example and show what you are trying to do, and then go from there?

Comment: Keep in mind that the folks here haven't all taken Discrete Mathematics, and even most who have it's been a while. You really should try to explain how to do things in fairly simple terms...

Comment: given two sets A and B I need to find and display each onto function from A to B. Let me take the example: A={1,2,3} B={a,b} number of onto functions is 2^3-2=6. I need to display all 6 functions that can exist from A to B in the form of ordered pairs. f1={(1,a),(2,b),(3,b)} f2={(1,b),(2,a),(3,b)} f3={(1,b),(2,b),(3,a)} and so on. I need to write a C code to display all these functions.

Comment: Man! Unless the sets are small that going to get to be a lot of functions in a hurry.

Comment: A function f:A->B is called onto if f(A) = B i.e if for all bEB there is at least one aEA with f(a) = b

Comment: I need to show sample outputs to the teacher. So most likely he will ask for trivial cases. I need to write function to display onto functions for trivial cases.

Comment: how many combinations are for 4 digits, and 4 letters?

Comment: For m=4 and n=4 there are 4^4 - 4(3^4) + 6(2^4) - 4(1^4) = 24 functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered a similar problem sometime ago but m and n were equal `m = n`.(You must think recursively to solve this), by your comment I think the possible answers are: `{(1,a)(2,b)(3,c)}, {(2,a)(3,b)(1,c)}, {(3,a)(1,b)(2,c)}, {(3,a)(2,b)(1,c)}, {(2,a)(1,b)(3,c)} and {(1,a)(3,b)(2,c)}` then this is my recipe:

1. Set 2 arrays with their initial value let's call them `letters` and `numbers`.

   ```
   *---*---*---*                          *---*---*---*
   | a | b | c | <---letters.             | 1 | 2 | 3 | <---numbers.
   *---*---*---*                          *---*---*---*
   ```
2. Choose one of the arrays to be your pivot, I chose the `letters`, it will be statical.

   ```
   *---*---*---*                          *---*---*---*
   | a | b | c | <---STATIC.              | 1 | 2 | 3 | <---DYNAMIC.
   *---*---*---*                          *---*---*---*
   ```
3. Rotate the dynamic array counter-clockwise or clockwise as you wish, you must print the `i element of numbers` with the `i element of letters`.

   ```
   *---*---*---*               *---*---*---*                 *---*---*---* 
   | 1 | 2 | 3 |   -(Print)->  | 2 | 3 | 1 |    -(Print)->   | 3 | 1 | 2 |
   *---*---*---*               *---*---*---*                 *---*---*---*
   ```

So you get at this point: `{(1,a)(2,b)(3,c)}, {(2,a)(3,b)(1,c)}, {(3,a)(1,b)(2,c)}`, 3 are missing.

1. Swap the `i element` with the `n element` of the dynamic array.

   ```
   *---*---*---*                                     *---*---*---*
   | 1 | 2 | 3 |   ---------( Swap (0<->2) )-------> | 3 | 2 | 1 | 
   *---*---*---*                                     *---*---*---*
   ```
2. Repeat the step 3.

   ```
   *---*---*---*               *---*---*---*                 *---*---*---* 
   | 3 | 2 | 1 |   -(Print)->  | 2 | 1 | 3 |    -(Print)->   | 1 | 3 | 2 |
   *---*---*---*               *---*---*---*                 *---*---*---*
   ```

So you get the missed subsets:`{(3,a)(2,b)(1,c)}, {(2,a)(1,b)(3,c)} and {(1,a)(3,b)(2,c)}`.

If you have more than 3 example 4. Easy: `1234` (rotate N times where N is the number of variables and print with each movement), swap 1 and 4 -> `4231` (Rotate and Print), swap 2 and 3 -> `4321` (Rotate and Print), swap 4 and 1 --> `1324` (Rotate and Print).

I hope this helped.

Comment: Answering a homework question without posting code to paste gets you a `+1` from me automatically.